# Validar formulario se variável1 é maior que a variavel2

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Olá, estou com criando um formulário onde a pessoa deve fornecer dois valores, um limite inferior e um superior, caso o limite inferior for maior que o superior eu gostaria que fosse gerado uma mensagem de erro! antes do form ser enviado.
Eu consegui fazer ele "funcionar", porém quando informo numeros pares no primeiro input, a validação se perde e retorna como se nada fosse digitado (ultimo else).

```js
var input2 = $('#limiteinf');
var input3 = $('#limitesup');
var saida2 = $('.help-block2');

input2.on('input', function() {
  atualiza2();
});
input3.on('input', function() {
  atualiza2();
});

function atualiza2() {
  var inferior2 = $("#limiteinf").val();
  var superior2 = $("#limitesup").val();
  var inferior = parseFloat(inferior2);
  var superior = parseFloat(superior2);
  if (inferior & superior != '') {

    if (inferior > superior) {
      $(".help-block2").html("O limite inferior deve ser menor que o Superior!");
      $('#validalimite').removeClass("has-success");
      $('#validalimite').addClass('has-error');
    }
    // Se resposta for false, ou seja, não ocorreu nenhum erro
    else {
      // Exibe mensagem de sucesso
      $(".help-block2").html("");
      $('#validalimite').removeClass("has-error");
      $('#validalimite').addClass('has-success');
      // Coloca a mensagem no div de mensagens
    }
  } else {
    $('#validalimite').removeClass("has-success");
    $('#validalimite').removeClass("has-error");
    $('#validalimite').addClass('has-error');
    $(".help-block2").html("Informe os LIMITES!");
  }

  // saida.html('exibe resultado...');
  //aqui você pode chamar a função ajax
}
}
```

```html
<input id="limiteinf" placeholder="Limite inferior" pattern="[0-9]+$"></input>
<span>e</span>
<input id="limitesup" placeholder="Limite superior" pattern="[0-9]+$"></input>
<p class="help-block2"></p>
```

Comment: Mas o evento está funcionado certinho?

Comment: O teu código tem erros de sintaxe. Podes corrigir?

Comment: o pior que com número ímpar estava funcionando, nem me liguei de ver o &&, mas como o gabriel informou, estava faltando mais um &.

De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O operador lógico *and* do primeiro if não está correto, por isso está caindo sempre no else.

O certo seria `&&` em vez de `&`.

Também parece que existe uma `}` desnecessária no fim.

Comment: Nossa, pensar que fiquei ontem procurando o que tinha feito errado -.-

Não da pra fazer as coisas com sono mesmo não, obrigado @Gabriel